# Reshape.error tensorflow -- [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32]....,

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm basically trying to read images as a batch using tfrecords, but I'm running into this error. It seems to be resizing the images correctly according to the print statement, but I'm getting the error at the end of print statement.

Part of the traceback error looks like this:

```
   next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Moondra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 40400 values, but the requested shape has 30300
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodeRaw, stack)]]
```

print statements before the traceback error (batch shape look correct):

```
(5, 200, 200, 3)
(5, 200, 200, 3)
(5, 200, 200, 3)
```

my code

```
 #tfrecords and batch images

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import os
import tensorflow as tf



IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200
IMAGE_WIDTH = 200


tfrecords_filename = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\Transfer Learning Tutorials\testing.tfrecords'

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
      features={
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        })

    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)


    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

    image_shape = tf.stack([height, width, 3])


    image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)


    #image_size_const = tf.constant((IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3), dtype=tf.int32)
    resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image=image,
                                           target_height=200,
                                           target_width=200)

    images = tf.train.shuffle_batch([resized_image], batch_size = 5,
                                    num_threads = 3, capacity=30,
                                     min_after_dequeue=10)

    return images



filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    [tfrecords_filename], num_epochs=10)

image = read_and_decode(filename_queue)


init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)


    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord =coord)

    for i in range(3):
        img = sess.run(image)
        print(img.shape)


    coord.request_stop()
    corrd.join(threads)
```

Comment: Can you share `testing.tfrecords` to reproduce this?

Comment: @Maxim, actually oddly, after a few runs of the script, the error disappeared. I'm not running into the problem anymore, and not exactly sure what fixed it.